# div height (percentage) not working with doctype

Tags: html, slider, height, doctype, swiper.js

I want my (swiper)slide to have a height of 65% of the total screen height. 
But it's not working when I add . 
My slider div is inside another div, I tried to give the outer div a height of 100% but this also isn't working.

Can someone help me?

Current html:

```
    <div class="page-wrap">
<div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Slider main container -->
        <div class="swiper-container">
            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                <!-- Slide -->
                <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url('http://cbs.umn.edu/sites/cbs.umn.edu/files/public/african_lion_king-wide_1.jpg')">
                    <div><h1>test</h1></div>
                </div>
                <!-- Add Pagination -->
                <div class="swiper-pagination swiper-pagination-white"></div>
                <!-- Add Arrows -->
                <div class="swiper-button-next swiper-button-white"></div>
                <div class="swiper-button-prev swiper-button-white"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

<div class="col-md-12 content">
    <p>hello world!</p>
</div>

</div>
<!-- end container -->

</div>
<!-- end wrapper -->

<div class="parallax">
    <section class="footersection">

    <div class="container footer verticalcenter" >
        <div class="inner-footer ">

            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h2>Footer</h2>
            </div>
         </div>
    </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Live xample is here:
http://jsfiddle.net/dreejt/gtm29r9k/

Answer (score 0):

I'm still a newbie myself, but I think it might be caused by `position: relative;` of `.page-wrap`

I tried this in your css, and it seemed to work.

```
.container-fluid {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%; }
```